# IE11 Console: Increase stack trace depth

Tags: stack-trace, internet-explorer-11, console.log, chakra

In Chrome, you can increase the stack trace depth by setting a flag at runtime (using `--js-flags="--stack-trace-limit <value>"`), or through the console (using `Error.stackTraceLimit`), explained here: https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi

This is also possible in Firebug, from what I understand, although I'm not as familiar with the intricacies of that tool.

Is there any provision for this in IE11? I'm dealing with an IE-specific issue, and the stack trace doesn't shed any light beyond my library's code (AngularJS). Increasing the stack trace depth would likely help me here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that no documented [Command Line Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exists that would offer this control. You can, however, increase the stack trace in Internet Explorer much like you would other popular browsers:

```js
Error.stackTraceLimit = 20; // The default is 10
```

Internet Explorer has supported this property on the Error constructor since version 10. It will not work in versions prior to that. In 2012 the [IEBlog demonstrated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/05/10/diagnosing-javascript-errors-faster-with-error-stack.aspx) some sample use of this property, as well as use of `Error.stack`.

There doesn't appear to be any way to persist this *setting* for all page requests. The only option I could suggest here would be to setup a proxy that adds this to all server responses. Naturally I would encourage [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for this.

Like other browsers, Internet Explorer 11 supports [`console.trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#traces). So you need not wait for an error to get your stack trace. You can invoke it arbitrarily at any time.

One last feature to look at would be [profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can control profiling sessions via `console.profile` and `console.profileEnd` (both of which are fairly standard) if you wish to capture only a specific slice of your applications lifecycle.

Comment: As it turns out, I found the answer just by guessing what it might have been, and the autocomplete in the console confirmed my guess.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this by simply playing around in the console - I knew there was an `Error` object. As it turns out, the `Error` object in IE11 supports the same `stackTraceLimit` property that Chrome and Firebug do (I guess they standardized it, finally). This can be set in the console, similar to Google Chrome (example: `Error.stackTraceLimit = 30`) and it will persist from the time you set it until the next navigation event - going back, forward, anywhere else, or refreshing the page.

The default for the stackTraceLimit is 10.

I needed to set this when the page loaded to debug an error, and so I was able to set an early breakpoint and manually set `Error.stackTraceLimit`. I haven't found a way to make this persist across navigation yet, and I don't know if there's a startup flag or anything to set it in a more permanent fashion. (I'd postulate that there's a registry entry somewhere.)

I hope this helps someone else who comes across this issue. Of note, the new IE11 tools will autocomplete properties of a native object, which is actually pretty nice, so you can quickly see what other properties and methods the `Error` object has. (This is actually how I found the property in question.)

Comment: Excellent find. The [IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/05/10/diagnosing-javascript-errors-faster-with-error-stack.aspx) discussed this some time back.